# An anime where a boy, who can eject fire from his finger, saves a girl from black-suited men

Tags: kaze-no-stigma

In the anime, the girl was sitting on some boxes of wood as the boy with fire powers passed by. The boy noticed the girl and adored her singing, and he approached the girl. When the girl finished singing, she started talking to the boy.

However, suddenly, evil men in black suits came, and they had some powers. They wanted to take the girl away, but since the boy was of a certain clan, with his awesome fire powers, he ejected fire from his finger, frightened the men, drove them away, and saved the girl.

It was aired around the same time when *Kekkaishi*, *Slam Dunk* and *Japanese Classic Horror* was shown on Animax India in 2010.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is looking for the same anime, I just got the name of it from Google.
It was [**Kaze no Stigma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaze_no_Stigma). However, the story remains incomplete as the author of the light novel series died in June, 2009.